# Make website non-responsive when there is no Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, responsive-design

Because I am using a responsive website that would rely on Javascript (Foundation top-bar), if the javascript is disabled, then it is impossible for the user to navigate throughout the site. So, is there a way to make the website non-responsive, i.e. making the website think that it's on a desktop, inside the `<noscript>` tag?

I have researched and could not find anything related to this matter.

Comment: You could isolate your media queries in a CSS file and load that file dynamically via a script. No scripting, no responsiveness, problem solved.

Comment: I cannot isolate the components that make responsiveness because the css file is dumped in one file.

Comment: In that case you may want to go the Modernizr way: modify your CSS rules to only apply if the `<body>` exposes a certain class, than add that class dynamically from a script on page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this is to assign different layouts for different screen sizes. For example, **ZURB Foundation** has the capability of hiding or showing contents on a specific screen size using the tag `.show-for-small-only` and so on, so combining it with the `<noscript>` tag, a non-responsive layout can be displayed only in a small screen, no JavaScript device.

Answer (score 2):

You will have add some other css in that case

```
<noscript>
  <style link="link_to_file.css"/>
</noscript>
```

Comment: What kind of CSS file are you talking about? This does not help because I have no idea which component to override, as all resources in the internet are about non responsive grids, not navs.